# AVAudioPlayer or MPMusicPlayerController for playing simentanously & in background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have the following needs to audio: it needs to be able to play at least 2 local audio files and it need to support playing in the background, so the user can close the app and multitask while the audio still plays. What of the 2 options are the best bet?

Comment: Are the local files in the device's iPod Library? AFAIK MPMusicPlayerController is used for local files inside the iPod Library.

Answer (score 0):

AVAudioPlayer is your best bet. As mentioned in the comment "AFAIK MPMusicPlayerController is used for local files inside the iPod Library."

Having said that, can you please give more details about your problem?